# Unable to upload Image at Cloudinary in Rails 5 via Image URL through seed file

Tags: file-upload, cloudinary, ruby-on-rails-5.2

```
DATA =[
['Post One','https://loremflickr.com/cache/resized/3772_33039069700_76194a71fd_c_640_480_red.jpg'],
['Post Two', 'https://loremflickr.com/cache/resized/2638_5733134374_e02bf20576_z_640_480_red.jpg'],
['Post 3', 'https://loremflickr.com/cache/resized/5085_5279023879_28b5302d5e_z_640_480_red.jpg']
]

DATA.each do |post|
  Post.create!(
    title: post[0],
    image: Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(IMAGE_URL.sample))
  )
  puts "Post : #{post[0]}"
end

Unable to upload the image

Error : CloudinaryException: Resource not found - 
https://loremflickr.com/cache/resized/2638_5733134374_e02bf20576_z_640_480_red.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the image you're trying to access doesn't exist.

```
$ curl -s -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}' https://loremflickr.com/cache/resized/2638_5733134374_e02bf20576_z_640_480_red.jpg

404
```

Another possibility is that the resource you're trying to access requires authentication or is restricted, but that would usually return a `401` or `403`, but is sometimes manually overwritten to `404`.